# How do I make when user type in text input then automatically it will convert to uppercase in it also change in db mysql

Tags: php, mysql

what php code and mysql code to make user type in text input then automatically it will change to uppercase and also change in db mysql

Comment: You're joking, right? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: A Google search would answer this question very quickly. I tend to think SO is for that esoteric stuff that isn't obvious. But that's just me...

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
strtoupper($string);
```

javascript:

```
string.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: i already put it but when i test it the database still wont change

Answer (score 1):

Start off by setting the CSS class for the input field to...

```
text-transform: uppercase
```

This will give the illusion that the text is being entered as such.

Then use PHP's strtoupper function to do the conversion...

```
$myString = strtoupper($myString);
```

Or you can use JavaScript to do the conversion...

```
myString.toUpperCase();
```

Or you could even have MySQL do the work...

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myField) VALUES(UPPER(myString));
```

Comment: input.uppercase {
text-transform: uppercase;
}                                                              <script type = "text/javascript">
function changeItPermanently() {
var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("txt1").value = x;
alert (document.getElementById("txt1").value);
}                                                                   <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="60" class="uppercase">

Comment: it still won't change the data in mysql database too

Comment: You can either insert a converted string into your MySQL table, or do the conversion in the query itself. That part is up to you. You are the architect, you are in control.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

http://www.marathon-studios.com/blog/mysql-ucase-and-lcas/
kindly have a look at it for upper case
for eg:-

```
<?php
$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";
$str = strtoupper($str);
echo $str; // Prints MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB AND SHE LOVED IT SO
?>
```

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript">
function changeItPermanently() {
var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("txt1").value = x;
alert (document.getElementById("txt1").value);
}

Comment: there are many ways to do that